# How to speed up applying decimate modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I have a dense mesh with uniform density. Each polygon is of about the same size. Details are varying, so I can reduce the mesh and still keep most of the shapes. So I add a decimate modifier.

When I set the level of decimation, it takes time as there is a lot of calculations. Sometimes minutes.

But when those calculations are done, I apply the modifier, it takes the same time again.

I am guessing that the first calculation is discarded and done again for some reason. Is there a way to work around it. I think it is this way for all modifiers but mainly noticed it for decimate (also booleans).